# How can I implement a SOCKS proxy to make requests to the whois protocol?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, socks, whois

Having trouble wrapping my head around making requests through the SOCKS proxy to whois.lookup.

I have a socks proxy (smartproxy) and a node server. I've tried tunnel, request, socks-proxy-agent,  It seems I'm missing the mark completely.

Example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
const whois = require('whois');
const { SocksProxyAgent } = require('socks-proxy-agent');

const domain = 'google.com';

const proxyAgent = new SocksProxyAgent(`socks5://myproxy`);

whois.lookup(domain, { proxy: proxyAgent }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('WHOIS Data:', data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code so we can answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I've added an example @bogdanoff

Answer (score 0):

From README page, `whois` package has builtin option for communicating with socks proxies. You just need to config it and no need to use `socks-proxy-agent`.

```js
const whois = require('whois');
const domain = 'google.com';

whois.lookup(domain, { proxy: { host: "myproxy", port: 8080 , type: 5 }  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('WHOIS Data:', data);
    }
});
```